# WordPress 2014 Theme - Background Color for: Header, Footer, Side Bar, Page and Post

Tags: wordpress

I'm still new to WP and I don't know where I can change those colors in the Editor (I understand that I must create a child theme first so not to disturb the original codes).

Regards.

Edit:

I can't even get the child theme to function properly:

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Fourteen Child
Theme URI: xxxhttp://www.xxx.xxx/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen-child/
Description: Twenty Fourteen Child Theme
Author: John Doe
Author URI: xxxhttp://www.xxx.xxx
Template: twentyfourteen
Version: 1.0.0
*/

@import url("xxxhttp://www.xxx.xxx/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/style.css");

/* =Theme customization starts here
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Activated the theme, but nothing show: xxxhttp://i.imgur.com/mOq1h7z.png

But the theme details are correct: xxxhttp://i.imgur.com/wxZoxok.png

Yet nothing show on the blog: xxxhttp://i.imgur.com/g5ujPdL.png

Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this in the visual editor that comes with WordPress (for the Twenty Fourteen theme, that is).

You are correct about child themes. I highly recommend creating your own child theme before tampering with the style sheets.

[How to create a child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme)

When you have created your child theme you can add CSS rules to it.

Example of child theme style.css file with a CSS rule to change your footer background color:

```
/*
 Theme Name:     user3134685's theme
 Theme URI:      http://example.org
 Description:    user3134685's theme
 Author:         User 3134685
 Author URI:     http://example.org
 Template:       twentyfourteen
 Version:        1.0.0
*/

@import url("../twentyfourteen/style.css");

/* =Theme customization starts here
-------------------------------------------------------------- */


.site-footer{
background-color:#770000; /*Dark red*/
}
```

The rest of the elements that you want to change have similar CSS classes or ID's that you will have to type in your style.css file. You can easily figure them out by using a web developer tool like Firebug and the element inspector tool.

Answer (score 1):

```
  There are two ways:
  1) Right click on front site and inspect element and find the line number of 
     style.css and edit whatever you want.

  2) Follow given screenshot in admin:![Appearance->Background or Header][1]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnJLj.png
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a child theme, which is basically creating a child style.css for your twenty fourteen theme. You can use a free editor such as Notepad++ to edit your child style.css. After activating your child theme from dashboard (what you did is correct), add all your modifications to the bottom of this same file.

For more information, you can check out [Twenty Fourteen Child Theme](http://techdwarf.com/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial/) and also [How to Customize Twenty Fourteen Theme](http://techdwarf.com/customize-twenty-fourteen-theme-wordpress/).